# Node No Longer Exists in SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a problem that I cannot seem to fix.  The code below will return a php error "*Node no longer exists*" when `$array` is empty.  If `$array` is not empty it works fine. The error will show up for the line with `$prinid = $array[0];` when `$array` is empty.

```
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA); 

foreach($doc as $a => $b) {
    if ($a == 'principal-list') {
        $array = $b->principal->attributes();
    }
}

$prinid = $array[0];

if (isset($array[0])) {
    $currentuser = 1;
} else {
    $currentuser = 0;
}
```

#### Update:

Here is what I have now and I get:

> Warning: count() [function.count]: Node no longer exists in * * * * * * *

```
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA); 

foreach($doc as $a => $b) {
    if ($a == 'principal-list') {
        $array = $b->principal->attributes();
    }
}

$currentuser = 0;
if (isset($array) && count($array) > 0) {
    $prinid = $array[0];
    $currentuser = 1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  There may be a better way of laying out your code to do it, and it would also help readability a bit.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the attribute you are trying to get isn't there.  You should check that array isn't empty

```
if (isset($array) && count($array) > 0)
    $prinid = $array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($a == 'principal-list' && $b && $b->principal) {
    $array = $b->principal->attributes();
}
```

Important thing - check `$b->principal` - you need check this xml object for empty. If it is true then on any try resolve `$b->principal->attributes()` you can get this error.